# TestLink и присвоение кейвордов на сьют

Tags: тестирование

Есть база тестов (~1500 штук) в тест-линке. У этих тестов сложная система кейвордов (приоритеты, FURPS+, принадлежность к фича-реквесту и т.д.). Недавно появилась потребность в двух новых кейвордах (зависимость/независимость результатов теста от бэкенда). Нужно просмотреть все тесты и каждому тесту добавить один из этих кейвордов.

Иногда бывает, что весь сьют можно спокойно отметить одним кейвордом. И очень хочется сделать это прямо пачкой. Но! Тест-линк имеет пренеприятную "особенность", если мы к имеющимся в сьюте кейвордам (а это все, что есть хоть у одного из тестов сьюта) добавим еще один (или уберем один) и нажмем кнопочку сохранить, то каждый тест получит *все* кейворды, которые были в сьюте.

Мануал тестлинка не помог, там написан ровно один способ и он работает вышеописанным образом. Это, естественно, нас не устраивает.

Собственно вопрос: Есть ли какой-то способ присваивать кейворды пачкам тестов, не ломая имеющееся?

Можно при помощи стороннего ПО, желательно бесплатного.

Не получится делать это штуками вроде Селениума. Потому что написание скриптов займет много больше времени, чем деланье этого руками.

P.S.: Я понимаю, что не совсем про программирование, но более подходящего форума я не нашла.